# Example of Mean.io Salesforce Implementation

Tags: heroku

I'm currently building a Heroku app and would like to use mean to build it. I've searched around but could not find any examples whatsoever. I'll be thankful if anyone can point me to a Salesforce web/ mobile app built using mean stack.

Comment: I m not sure if you will get any references here, but you can try posting it in [Mean developer channels](http://mean.io/#!/support) and see if you get any response

Comment: According to http://mean.io/ the Mean.io stack is mongoDB (a NoSQL database), express (node.js web application framework), AngularJS (client-side MVC), Node.Js (server platform). So what exactly do you want to use Salesforce for? To hold the data? To host the app too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mean.Io has a blog detailing installation steps of getting Mean on to Heroku:

http://blog.mean.io/2014/01/installing-mean-io-on-heroku-from-a-to-z/